Extract the start and end date of a sick leave in power query (gaps and islands)
I would like to have a max and min date of the different types of absence for every employee for project. I would like to have it in Power BI but I don't know how to do it.
There are 3 columns that this should be grouped: Project ID, Person ID and Time Status.
I thought about grouping also on Month and Year but then if there will be situation that there is 2 sick leaves in the same month it will not work properly. Here is an example of data:

And the outcome should be like that:

Thanks.
Here is the sample of the data:
Project ID  Person ID   Time Status     Date
10          1           Sick leave      21.06.2024
10          1           Sick leave      09.07.2024
10          1           Sick leave      10.07.2024
10          1           Sick leave      11.07.2024
10          1           Sick leave      12.07.2024
9           2           Annual leave    12.08.2024
9           2           Annual leave    13.08.2024
9           2           Annual leave    14.08.2024
9           2           Annual leave    15.08.2024
9           2           Annual leave    31.08.2024


Can you paste your data as copiable markdown text?

I have added it

In SQL this kind of problem is called "Gaps and Islands" and usually solved with window functions and PARTITION BY. You could maybe do something clunky in M with  ordering by Project ID, Person ID, Time Status, Date and then AddIndexColumn and a self join but looks like DAX does have window functions

How do you determine when one leave ends and the second sick leave starts when there are multiple leaves?

I only wanted to group this which are day by day

If you have a large set of data, the following will execute significantly faster.
It assumes the data is already sorted as you show in your example -- by dates ascending within each Project ID | Person ID. If they are not, then this will need to be sorted which will lengthen the processing time.
It uses an Index column and the 4th and 5th arguments of the Table.Group function to ensure the grouping is by consecutive dates:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Project ID", Int64.Type}, {"Person ID", Int64.Type}, {"Time Status", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),


    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Project ID", "Person ID", "Time Status","Date", "Index"}, {
        {"Start Date", each List.Min([Date]), type date},
        {"End Date", each List.Max([Date]), type date}
        }, GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Duration.Days(y[Date]-x[Date])- (y[Index]-x[Index]) ),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"


Clever solution Ron - upvoted

Really good solution, and it is also very fast, thank you

I added a GetStartAndEndDates function to check dates[i]-dates[i-1] for each projectId, personId and timeStatus.
If dates[i]-dates[i-1] > 1, I assume date[i] is the start of a new "leave".

let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
  Navigation = Source{[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  GetStartAndEndDates = (source as table)=> 
    let 
      sorted = Table.Sort(source, {{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
      addIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(sorted, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
      addDuration = Table.AddColumn(addIndex, "Duration", each if [Index] = 0 then 0 else Duration.Days([Date] - addIndex[Date]{[Index]-1}) ),
      addKey = Table.AddColumn(addDuration, "Key", each if [Index] = 0 then 0 else if [Duration] <= 1 then null else [Index]),
      filled = Table.FillDown(addKey, {"Key"}),
      results = Table.Group(filled, {"Key"}, {{"Start Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}, {"End Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}})
    in 
      results,
  grouped = Table.Group(Navigation, {"Project ID", "Person ID", "Time Status"}, {{"All", each _, type nullable table[#"Project ID" = any, #"Person ID" = any, #"Time Status" = any, Date = any]}}),
  startEndDates = Table.AddColumn(grouped, "StartEndDates", each GetStartAndEndDates([All])),
  expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(startEndDates, "StartEndDates", {"Start Date", "End Date"}, {"Start Date", "End Date"}),
  removed = Table.RemoveColumns(expanded, {"All"})
in
  removed



let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project ID", Int64.Type}, {"Person ID", Int64.Type}, {"Time Status", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Sequence", each try if Value.Is( Record.Field( #"Changed Type"{[Project ID = [Project ID], Date =  Date.AddDays( [Date],-1)] }, "Date") , type date) then null else [Date] otherwise [Date]),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Sequence"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Project ID", "Person ID", "Time Status", "Sequence"}, {{"Start", each List.Min([Date]), type date}, {"End", each List.Max([Date]), type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Sequence", "Date"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"


It is nt working for big amount of data, it returns date in Sequence column

I thought the other solution worked for you as you accepted it as an answer? This solution works with your sample data so please add more data to show where it breaks down in order to test it or try Ron's solution

Yes yes, I just wanted to answer to all of your ideas, but thank you for the effort, I am not checking Ron's solution

This should return date in the sequence column. I don't use an index as there is no need when we have a date already. The sequence column is then renamed to date to match your expected results.
